# The command 'npm run dev' is not working, what should I do?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I'm trying npm run dev in the cmd and it's throwing an error I've tried a lot of things but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my package.json file:

```
           {
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0"
  }
}
```

Here is my wepack.config.js:

```
    const path = require('path');


module.export = {
    entry: './src/js/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/js'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    mode: 'development'
};
```

I updated my npm, tried npm cache clean --force but and many other things but nothing seems to work. Please help.

This is the error I get:

```
  Insufficient number of arguments or no entry found.
Alternatively, run 'webpack(-cli) --help' for usage info.

Hash: c1735700111314ac598b
Version: webpack 4.43.0
Time: 62ms
Built at: 05/25/2020 1:24:29 PM

WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/

ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in 'C:\Users\usman\Desktop\coding\Forkify'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! forkify@1.0.0 dev: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the forkify@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\usman\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-25T08_24_29_792Z-debug.log.
```

Comment: please show project structure

Comment: could not find the path "./src/js/index.js"

Comment: "Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in 'C:\Users\usman\Desktop\coding\Forkify'" - the path to your entry file is invalid.

Comment: How come? I Made sure it is not invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I uninstalled webpack cli using PowerShell as administrator and installed it using PowerShell too, it worked perfectly for me. It is an administration problem so make sure to download cli using PowerShell. These were the commands that I used:

```
npm uninstall webpack webpack-cli
```

And for installation:

```
npm install webpack webpack-cli --save-dev
```

I hope I am being helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

can you try to change your webpack.config.js like this :

```
   const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/js/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/js"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    publicPath: "/js/",
  },
};
```

and also modify the scripts object inside  package.json file like below :

```
  "scripts": {
"serve": "webpack-dev-server --mode development"
```

},

and finally run this command : npm run serve

Comment: I still get an error, It says ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in 'C:\Users\usman\Desktop\coding\Forkify'

ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in 'C:\Users\usman\Desktop\coding\Forkify'
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src main[1]
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

Comment: Hello again i have create a webpack sample project for you it contains a simple index.js file as you already did, you will find the project in this  github link ( https://github.com/Noussair/webPackSample)  then you must proceed like this :

1- Download the project zip.
2- Unzip the projetc and open it with your favourite IDE.
3- Run this command : npm install
4- Excute this command : npm run serve

Comment: Thank you, but I got it and now it works just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your support! :)

Comment: You are welcome you can try the poject that i have created for you it contains devleoppement and production mode and it linked webpack and babel toghther :D